# React, создание компонента с таблицей

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map, table

Имею следующий код. Не могу разобраться почему не работает блок кода, расположенный в теге ? Буду очень благодарен за конструктивную помощь. В пропсы передается массив

```
const context = [{ "modelMachine": "ПД3,0", "factoryNumberMachine": "0032", "engine": "Kubota V3300" }, { "modelMachine": "ПД3,0", "factoryNumberMachine": "0003", "engine": "Kubota V3300" }]
```

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Table(props) {

  return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr key='head'>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {props.context.map(item=>{
              <tr key={item.factoryNumberMachine}>
                <td>{item.modelMachine}</td>
                <td>{item.factoryNumberMachine}</td>
                <td>{item.engine}</td>
              </tr>
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>  
  )
}
```

Comment: `return <tr key={....`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный* код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых давайте разберемся что такое `props.context`. по вашему мнению это `<Table :context={context} />` ?

Если да, то при создании объекта Table ему в изначальном состоянии props не передаются от слова совсем от туда скорее всего ошибка что `props.context` не инициализирован и у него нет функции map. У undefined нет функции map.

Первым шагом реакт создаёт Table, вторым он повторно вызывает функцию Table уже с наличием аттрибутов.

Я бы все-же изначально проверял что пропса это instanceof Array.

Я бы все-же вынес map из постройщика, а его детей в отдельный компонент, что-бы не убить реактивность компонентов.

Comment: ``` <Table  context={context}/> ``` пропсы, которые передаются в компонент. для проверки в map добавлял вывод в консоль item.factoryNumberMachine - map работает и массив итерируется

Comment: Попробуй мапнуть в `<tr><rd>{{JSON.stringify(item)}}</td></tr>` возможны потери значений, вообще что браузуер в отладке пишет? Может просто потеря значения? Так она вообще просто лечится... PS: один символ ` в коментариях

Comment: ...просто добавьте `return`

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @DiGrebenev можно поставить плюсик, если помог или правильный ответ, если ответ был верным.